# Как добавить динамики в игру?

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр

Есть проект, где персонаж скатывается вниз по зданию (бесконечно). Проблема в том, что я не могу сделать здание бесконечно длинным, ибо это будет тупо. Поэтому я создаю препятствия и двигаю их. Но из-за это пропал эффект "падения" или же "спуска". Возникает вопрос, как добавить динамики в геймплей? Есть идеи или хотя бы примеры из других игр?

[image: Скрин]

Comment: Вам нужно вернуть в игру эффект скатывания по крыше или просто добавить чего-то интересного?

Comment: Эффект скатывания. А то так не понятно, что он движется (несмотря на препятствия).

Answer (score 0):

Серое на картинке это, я так понимаю крыша, а зеленое - какое-то препятствие... Во-первых, можно попробовать немного повернуть камеру, что бы было видно небо и добавить на него облака, а чтобы было ощущение падения, сделайте, чтобы облака потихоньку не только плыли вбок, но и уходили вверх. Во-вторых, немного труднее, можно добавить птиц (клюющихся ворон, к примеру). В третьих, можно иногда сделать в крыше дырки - немного не реалистично, но все же - а в дырках можно увидеть комнату под крышей. Можно добавить трубы, хотя зеленое это похоже итак труба, тогда сделать трубы разноцветные и с дымом

Вы пишите, что не можете сделать здание бесконечным... То есть когда-то оно закончится? Тогда сделайте, чтобы игрок, когда крыша кончалась, падал с нее на батут на земле, подскакивал и бежал по следующей крыше. Или чтобы падал в какую-нибудь пещеру (хотя какая пещера рядом с домом). Можно конечно еще добавить, чтобы игрок периодически бежал вверх по крыше, если вы не считаете, что это противоречит замыслу игры. Валюты можно добавить: монеты, алмазы. Достижения. Но это уже больше по добавлению динамики, чем по возвращению эффекта скатывания с крыши.